# Why running Ratchet websocket server via php pends browser request?

Tags: php, ratchet

I'm building an hybrid mobile app with a framework. It's all good and now I want to update views when needed. So I thought about websockets.
After reading Ratchet doc, I've been able to set this server running with command lines. I know about deployment solution for making server run automatically but It's a bit complex for me. So I tried to run the server from php with this following code:

```
    ...

    $port = 8080;
    //echo("Starting server on port " . $port);
    $server = IoServer::factory(
        new HttpServer(
            new WsServer(
              $MessageHandler
            )
        ),
        $port
    );
    $server->run();
```

I make a request `http://localhost/app/ws/run-server` and it runs the server as expected but the browser pends this request and any others ones called after.
I then must comment this line `$server->run()` and restart Apache via XAMPP before I can go ahead.

So I really need a help because I've been searching for days and days.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should not run the web socket from the web server. You have to run it as a new process.

Comment: Yes already tried codes here https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html but it still pends...

Comment: After reading again doc but successless I'm back for asking what you really mean by "not ... from the web server".

Comment: You are executing the PHP script that runs the websocket via an HTTP call. This is... strange. You should run the websocket through an independent process.

Comment: I agree for the independant process. That's why I made an ajax request (where i run the websocket server with Symfony process component) and hoped on success to instanciate the websocket into my javascript.

Comment: I think this is a very valid question (upvoted it). I'd like to monitor the long running Ratchet process, stop or start it from a web-interface. Without exec() etc, that might not be so easy.

Answer (score 1):

I was in the same position: I wanted to quickly start/stop Ratchet from a web interface without having to resort to hacks that involve exec() or having to [install ZMQ](http://socketo.me/docs/push).

So what I did was: call the script that kicks off the Ratchet websocket server from cURL:

```
$options = [
    CURLOPT_URL => 'url/to/server.php',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => false,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => $method
    ];

                
// init
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array( $curl, $options );

// exec
curl_exec( $curl );
curl_close( $curl );
```

Parts of interest: `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS` to a really low value, `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to false (not totally sure about that one though). This cURL call will immediately return and will not block the rest of your script execution.

Stopping it is not possible without ZMQ or talking to the webserver layer of the Ratchet Websocket server (not sure how to do that, and if it's possible at all). The script runs forever, unless it crashes. I communicate with the script through WebSockets from then on, also for administrative access like stopping it. But there may be other (better) ways to do that.